# What does "?" mean in Unix/Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm currently learning Bash and trying to understand some lines of code which I've found.

So from my understanding,

```
* refers to everything within the specified file/directory
? refers to one single character
```

and based off this understanding, I found the code down below and I'm trying to understand it but to no avail.

Can someone please explain what is happening in this line of code?

```
mv public_html/*.??g public_html/images/
```

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-globbing

Answer (score 1):

```
mv public_html/*.??g public_html/images
```

Move all files in the directory  `public_html` that have a 3 character extension ending in `g` to its subfolder `images`.

Answer (score 0):

`*` is not everything in the directory unless it is all by itself.

`public_html/*.??g`  --> `public_html/` <kbd>anything</kbd> `.` <kbd>single character</kbd> <kbd>single character</kbd> `g`

Technically, `*` isn't <kbd>anything</kbd> either, it's anything that isn't a `/`

This may match multiple files, which is ok, because the last pathname on the line appears to be a directory.

To describe this in words, move anything in the `public_html` directory that ends in a three letter file extension ending in `g` into the `images` subdirectory.

Comment: oh okay, so if its * on its own then its everything, but if its like a*, then its anything thats not a?

Comment: @Deezel `a*` would be anything that starts with "a". BTW, these meaning apply when these "wildcard" characters are used as part of a regular command and *not* quoted or escaped (and not in a `$(( ))` expression, or...). They also apply in a few other places). In other situations, they can have completely different meanings. Shell syntax is *very* context-dependent, so a lot of things have different meanings depending on where they are.

Comment: Think of it like a template.  With `a*`  the `a` is literal and the `*` is replaced by something.